# Identify this X-Men scene?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men, episode-identification

I remember watching a X-Men cartoon scene on TV in 90s. My cartoon senses say that it wasn't the popular *X-Men: The Animated series*. Here are the details I remember:

- Extended hands were shown from first person view perspective (like Superman sees his hands while flying). The guy was flying from the space into the atmosphere.
- He reached the roof where he found a mutant which I failed to recognize (I never encountered him again).
- The mutant attacked him by very high wind blown from his mouth. There was probably two more attacks (by the mutant on the roof) which I don't remember. The mutant won.
- Again something flying into the atmosphere from the space (the same way as the previous guy). This one turned out to be Phoenix.
- The mutant on the roof attacked the same way (with the all three attacks), but nothing worked.
- The Phoenix then blew the mutant off the roof by yellow fire.

Sorry for such a blurred short description. I was a kid then and I don't remember more details. Can you please identify this X-Men cartoon scene?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't found mention of the rooftop battle in a transcript, but the Phoenix Saga in Season 3 of *X-Men the Animated Series* includes scenes on the roof of Cassidy Keep. Being the house of Banshee and Siren, I could see it likely they might be repelling someone by their sonic shouts, which could resemble wind coming out of their mouths. It would probably be somewhere in episodes 5-7 as [Episode 7](http://comicsalliance.com/the-x-men-episode-guide-3x07-the-phoenix-saga-part-iv-the-starjammers/) apparently starts with them on the roof post-battle.

An image from [Episode 5](http://comicsalliance.com/the-x-men-episode-guide-3x05-the-phoenix-saga-part-2-cry-of-the-banshee/) does show the outstretched arm shot:
[image: Outstretched arms with red gloves, headed for a distant building on an isle]

Gladiator comes in around the 13 minute mark of the episode.

Comment: The X-Men Episode Guide 3×05: ‘The Phoenix Saga, Part 2: Cry Of The Banshee’

Read More: The X-Men Episode Guide 3x05: 'The Phoenix Saga, Part 2: Cry Of The Banshee' | http://comicsalliance.com/the-x-men-episode-guide-3x05-the-phoenix-saga-part-2-cry-of-the-banshee/?trackback=tsmclip | The arms belong to Gladiator, the most powerful member of the Shiar's Imperial Guard.

Comment: I love the squeaky voices in the video, lol! Seems it might be a little compressed ...

Comment: @Thaddeus: Thanks for the link to Comics Alliance. That's where I got the image from. It made me realize that I'd forgotten to actually add the links to the article.

Comment: No worries, my friend. I want to be helpful as well. Don't want people to think I am only here for the reputation...

Comment: It was the Gladiator which attacked with wind blow. I mixed it all. He failed to smash Phoenix with the same attack.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: Ah, good good. Glad we could help.