# Episode from "X-Men: The Animated Series" where all the X-Men are defeated by a single individual

Tags: marvel, x-men, episode-identification, x-men-the-animated-series

While scrolling through the *X-Men* section in the Disney+ catalog, I started to remember a scene from the 90s *X-Men: The Animated Series*. As far as I remember, this was a multipart episode that ended like this:

> All the X-Men (and maybe Magneto's gang) were defeated by a humanoid (alien?) individual. The individual then started to board a UFO-like vehicle. Magneto tried to stop it but was immediately defeated by the individual, and the episode ends.

Before starting to fully watch *X-Men* again, I'd like to know the name of the episode.

Comment: I can't recall if Magneto fought Apocolypse but that seems like a likely candidate. So probably "Come the Apocolypse" or subsequent episodes

Comment: Forgot to mention, the individual looked like Silver Surfer but it might not have his surfing board, so I doubt it was apocalypse. Will watch it later on anyway.

Comment: Arkon and Erik the Red were going to be my suggestions until you said they looked like Silver Surfer. :-D Plus, neither is noted to have fought Magneto.

Comment: I haven't seen the show in like a decade+ but I think if he had powers like the Silver Surfer it could have been Galactus? He doesn't really look like the Surfer, but I'd imagine he could defeat everyone and jump on a ship

Comment: It reminds me of a video in which a Superman lookalike takes out the Juggernaut before taking out the rest of the X-Men who attempt to stop him.

Comment: @Clockwork That would be Gladiator as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87146/identify-this-x-men-scene/87151#87151

Answer (score 6):

I don't know this entirely fits, but the episode [Mojovision](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0751322/) (S2E11, or Episode 24) features [Spiral](https://marvelanimated.fandom.com/wiki/Spiral) capturing most of the X-Men and taking them to an alien world.

There's a long-running sub-arc in Season 2 where Xavier and Magento are trapped in the Savage Lands (without their mutant powers) and this particular episode ends with a pterodactyl-like creature named Sauron capturing and carrying off [Shanna](https://marvelanimated.fandom.com/wiki/Shanna), while Xavier and Magento look on helplessly. The Mojo story is not part of this sub-arc, however.

Comment: I'll check both later on. Although, I highly doubt it is the second option because magneto did use his powers against the individual.